# Not able to see value of increment button

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

New to `react` and I am removing the local state in my `counter` component and will be relying on the `props` to receive the data that it needs. I believe this is called a `controlled component`. After I got rid of the `state` and changed every where I was using `this.state` to `this.props`, I am no longer able to see the box that displays the value when I click my `increment` button. I will post all the code down below.

/* Counter Component*/

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

class Counter extends Component {
renderTags() {
return (
  <ul>
    {this.state.tags.length === 0 && <p> There are no tags </p>}
    {this.state.tags.map(tag => (
      <li key={tag}> {tag} </li>
    ))}
  </ul>
    );
  }

  // You can do styles this way or do it inline
  //   styles = {
  //     fontSize: 50,
  //     fontWeight: "bold"
  //   };


 render() {
 return (
  <div>
    <span style={{ fontSize: 20 }} className={this.getBadgeClasses()}>
      {this.formatCount()}
    </span>
    <button
      onClick={() => this.props.onIncrement(this.props.counter)}
      className="btn btn-secondary btn-sm"
    >
      Increment
    </button>

    <button
      onClick={() => this.props.onDelete(this.props.counter.id)}
      className="btn btn-danger btn-sm m-2"
    >
      Delete
    </button>

    {/* {this.renderTags()}
    <p>{this.state.tags.length === 0 && "Please create a new tag"}</p> */}
  </div>
);
 }

  getBadgeClasses() {
    let classes = "badge m-2 badge-";
    classes += this.props.counter.value === 0 ? "warning" : "primary";
    return classes;
  }

 formatCount() {
const { count } = this.props.counter;
return count === 0 ? "Zero" : count;
  }
}

export default Counter;
```

/* Counters Component */

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Counter from "./counter";

class Counters extends Component {
 state = {
counters: [
  { id: 1, value: 5 },
  { id: 2, value: 0 },
  { id: 3, value: 0 },
  { id: 4, value: 0 }
]
 };

 handleIncrement = counter => {
console.log(counter);
};

  handleReset = () => {
   const counters = this.state.counters.map(c => {
  c.value = 0;
  return c;
});
this.setState({ counters });
  };

 handleDelete = counterID => {
const counters = this.state.counters.filter(c => c.id !== 
   counterID);
   this.setState({ counters });
 };

 render() {
   return (
  <React.Fragment>
    <button onClick={this.handleReset} className="btn btn-dark btn-sm m-2">
      Reset
    </button>
    {this.state.counters.map(counter => (
      <Counter
        key={counter.id}
        onDelete={this.handleDelete}
        counter={counter}
        onIncrement={this.handleIncrement}
      />
    ))}
  </React.Fragment>
   );
    }
  } 

  export default Counters;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't see the values since you are using a wrong `key` for your `counter`.

```
formatCount() {
    const { count } = this.props.counter;
    return count === 0 ? "Zero" : count;
}
```

There isn't any key named `count` in your counter. It is value. So, you should use it or you need to destruct it like this:

```
const { value: count } = this.props.counter
```

But, using the same name is more consistent I think. Also, your `Counter` component would be a stateless one since you don't need any state or lifecycle method there.

One extra change would be done to the handler methods like `onClick` for `onIncrement`. If you use an arrow function, that function will be recreated in every render. You can use an extra handler method. Here is the complete working example (simplified for a clear view).

```js
class Counters extends React.Component {
  state = {
    counters: [
      { id: 1, value: 5 },
      { id: 2, value: 0 },
      { id: 3, value: 0 },
      { id: 4, value: 0 }
    ]
  };

  handleIncrement = counter => {
    const { counters } = this.state;
    const newCounters = counters.map( el => {
      if( el.id !== counter.id ) { return el; }
      return { ...counter, value: counter.value + 1 }
    } )
    this.setState({ counters: newCounters});
  };

  handleReset = () => {
    const counters = this.state.counters.map(c => {
      c.value = 0;
      return c;
    });
    this.setState({ counters });
  };

  handleDelete = counter => {
    const { id: counterID } = counter;
    const counters = this.state.counters.filter(c => c.id !== counterID);
    this.setState({ counters });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.handleReset} className="btn btn-dark btn-sm m-2">
          Reset
        </button>
        {this.state.counters.map(counter => (
          <Counter
            key={counter.id}
            onDelete={this.handleDelete}
            counter={counter}
            onIncrement={this.handleIncrement}
          />
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const Counter = props => {
  const { counter, onIncrement, onDelete} = props;

  function formatCount(){
    const { value } = counter;
    return value === 0 ? "Zero" : value;
  }

  function handleIncrement(){
    onIncrement( counter );
  }

  function handleDelete(){
    onDelete( counter );
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <span>
        {formatCount()}
      </span>
      <button
        onClick={handleIncrement}
      >
        Increment
        </button>

      <button
        onClick={handleDelete}
      >
        Delete
        </button>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<Counters />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I looked back at my code and noticed that I didn't change it either. I really like React and I plan on mastering it. Thanks for your help!